# Responsive CSS sprites with background-image property

Tags: css, httprequest, css-sprites

I found very useful tool for creating the responsive sprite images.
http://responsive-css.spritegen.com/

Unfortunately the sprites are generated as img tags and create own HTTP request.
Is there any elegant way how to do responsive CSS sprites with background-image property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a data-url. The image-bits can be embededed directly in your stylesheet. You could also embed the data-url in the src property of an image tag.

In a stylesheet, it looks like this:

```
    background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAACAQMAAACnuvRZAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAAJcEhZcwAACxIAAAsSAdLdfvwAAAAcdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEZpcmV3b3JrcyBDUzQGstOgAAAAFnRFWHRDcmVhdGlvbiBUaW1lADAxLzA0LzE0Kb6O2wAAAAxJREFUCJljeMDwAAADhAHBgGgjpQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
```

That's a data-url bg image for a 2x3 transparent png image (just for example -- it's small).

data-urls make sprites obsolete -- you can embed multiple data-urls instead of one sprite, and there are no extra http calls (in fact, it's one *less*).

You can easily generate one from an existing image. Here's an online tool: http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

Comment: does the browser count the data:image/png as http request or not? I can see it on the list with data requests in chrome, but I can't see  the time for processing/waiting by this one.

Comment: It does not *make* an http request for a data-url. Chrome developer tools will list it in the network tab, but rest assured there are no round-trips to the server for that resource.