# Responsive background images whilst using sprites

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-sprites

I'm developing a responsive website using `Twitter Bootstrap` and I want to make some background images responsive that are within a sprite.

Now, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655953/responsive-css-sprites-with-background-image-property) that appears to give a good method, but my issue is, what happens if the image is updated? Normally you could just use cache busting techniques such as appending something like `?v=2` to the end of the filename, but with this method I'm not sure if that is possible? ...or is caching not an issue with this method?

If caching is still an issue are there any other methods available? ...or something a bit more user-friendly than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching shouldn't be an issue provided you're using something other than a transparent gif.  Namely, because the size of the change to the file should be enough to tip the browser off that the file isn't the same when the page is visited.  Which handles client-side caching.

Server-side caching won't be an issue with this, as the server will know that the modification date is greater than the last file that was loaded, and *should* deliver the newer version.